# How to get the final output of of shell command executed by python

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to execute a shell command `kubectl get ns | grep -E '(^|\s)namespace-test($|\s)'` 
but I am getting empty even if there are errors or not.

**Reason I am getting empty** for both error and non error cases is it executes the command in two times (commands left and right to `|`), **But what I need is to get the actual output as a return value, say `0` if there is an output, or `1` if there is no output**

This is what I am trying:

```
get_ns_p1 = subprocess.Popen(['kubectl', 'get', 'ns'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
get_ns_p2 = subprocess.Popen(["grep", "-E", "\'(^|\s)"+NAMESPACE+"($|\s)\'"], stdin=get_ns_p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)


get_ns_p1.stdout.close() # Allow proc1 to receive a SIGPIPE if proc2 exits.
out_ns, err = get_ns_p2.communicate()

print(out_ns)
```

can someone help me?

or if you have any approach for this, **this is what I want to do...**

**I want to execute a shell command which has a `pipe` and get the output, if there is an output, it should return some value, if the output is empty it should gives a different value, if there is an `error` it should gives another different output**

How can I achieve this?

Comment: split command by pipe like this: `return [command for command in cmd.partition('|') if command != '|' if command != '']` then create `for` loop and call first element form list with `subprocess.Popen`, the next elements should be passed with the result of the previous command in `stdin`

Comment: Would you help me out with an example please? :) I am new to python

Comment: Take a look at answer. If it works, mark it as the correct solution. Regards

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2.7 - 3.x

#### Tested on CentOs

First of all, you have to split your command by pipe. Like this: `[command for command in cmd.partition('|') if command != '|' if command != '']`

After that, you have to start your `subprocess.Popen` command. The first time, execute the first item from the list, after that you can execute next elements, but you have to pass to `stdin` result of previous execution. This will allow you to execute your pipe command.

However, be careful with `shell=True`. More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess).

**Example  code**:

```
import logging
import subprocess  # nosec

logging.basicConfig(filename='log.log',
                    filemode='a',
                    format='%(asctime)s,%(msecs)d %(name)s %(levelname)s %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%H:%M:%S',
                    level=logging.INFO)

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def execute_and_create_output_from_cmd(cmd_parts):
    """
    Functions executes cmd and adds parsed lines to <List> result.
    :return: <List>
    """
    try:
        index = 0
        process = {}
        for cmd_part in cmd_parts:
            cmd_part = cmd_part.strip()
            if index == 0:
                process[index] = subprocess.Popen(cmd_part, shell=True,  # nosec
                                                  stdin=None, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
            else:
                process[index] = subprocess.Popen(cmd_part, shell=True,  # nosec
                                                  stdin=process[index - 1].stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                                  stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
            index += 1
        (output, err) = process[index - 1].communicate()
        exit_code = process[0].wait()

        if exit_code != 0:
            log.warning('Output: %s', output)
            log.error('Error: %s', err)
            log.error('Exit code: %s', exit_code)
        else:
            print(output)  # do whatever you want with your output
    except OSError as os_error:
        log.error('Could not execute command: %s', os_error)


def split_cmd(cmd):
    """ Split cmd command. Check if command contains '|'. '||' allowed. """
    return [command for command in cmd.partition('|') if command != '|' if command != '']


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cmd = split_cmd('ls -al | grep ibm')
    execute_and_create_output_from_cmd(cmd)
```

I have added `logging`. It is not necessary.

#### Output:

```bash
[kchojnowski@zabbix4-worker1 ~]$ python test.py
drwxrwxr-x  2 kchojnowski kchojnowski    50 Jul 24 15:33 ibm_mq
```

Comment: will try this and let you know